# Installing an internal library via bower

Tags: bower, bower-install

We have an internal library that can be installed via `bower install git link`. How do I add the git link inside the bower.json file so that when I run `bower install`, it will install it too?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't know it was easy. I just reinstalled it with --save and it updated my bower.json file. Now I know how it looks like inside the bower.json file.